# How to fix MySQL error in opencart?

Tags: mysql, opencart

I got this MySQL error.. and i changed my hosting firm.. i got new hosting now from godaddy.. please help me.. whats the solution ?

```
Notice: Error: Out of resources when opening file '/tmp/#sql_108e_0.MYI' (Errcode: 24)
Error No: 23

SELECT * FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON
    (c.category_id = cd.category_id)
LEFT JOIN category_to_store c2s ON
    (c.category_id = c2s.category_id)
WHERE
    c.parent_id = '0' AND
    cd.language_id = '2' AND
    c2s.store_id = '0'
    AND c.status = '1'
ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)
in /home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/database/mysql.php on line 49
```

Comment: your question is not much cleared can you elaborate in detail.

Comment: my site suddenly gives mysql error.. and it taken hourse 2-3 hourse then its fixed back normally.. i searched this error someones said "left join error" but i dont know how to fix.. my ex hosting firm said; it could be because of php.ini but my php.ini is deafult i didnt change i checked.. please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What this error typically means is that MySQL has exceeded the limit for the number of files you can open at once.  This is easy to fix in Linux by upping that number.

edit /etc/security/limits.conf

and add:
mysql soft nofile 4096
mysql hard nofile 4096

This effectively doubles the number of files MySQL can open (default is half this).

On windows you can’t really fix this.  It is an OS limitation. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits-windows.html

Also sometimes this error will fix by doing simple FLUSH operation on the tables.

So, First do FLUSH of mysql tables, and then make edit on the files to overcome from this issue.